# Azure event hub Azure function node js integration not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to fetch events from azure eventhub using a timer triggered azure function. I am able to fetch the events successfully with a simple nodejs code while running in my machine locally. But if the same code if i execute through a node js azure function, it doesn't work. I get the below error message. Is there something I am missing ?

```
TypeError: EventHubConsumerClient is not a constructor' Stack: TypeError: EventHubConsumerClient is not a constructor at Object.<anonymous>
```

Below is the sample code

```
const { ContainerClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");    
const { BlobCheckpointStore } = require("@azure/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob");

const connectionString = "Endpoint=xxxx";    
const eventHubName = "yyyy";
const consumerGroup = "default";
const storageConnectionString = "abcd";
const containerName = "eventhubcontainer";

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {

const containerClient = new ContainerClient(storageConnectionString, containerName);

const checkpointStore = new BlobCheckpointStore(containerClient);
const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName, checkpointStore);
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You are missing this line.

```
const { EventHubConsumerClient } = require("@azure/event-hubs");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass consumerGroup and the ConnectionString to the EventHubConsumerClient constructor

```
const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(this.consumerGroup, eventHubConnectionString);
```

Here is an [Example](https://github.com/AndreaVillegasGarcia/BeeSyncApp2/blob/0de3b94383854800d0e7f17225a6ed92c8aa1d82/scripts/event-hub-reader.js)

Comment: Got the issue, The `EventHubConsumerClient` package was now downloaded automatically in azure function. Need to add a package.json and run npm install manually to get it downloaded.

Comment: One other question - Is it possible to send message to event hub to a particular partition? Can someone help with a sample code?

Comment: You can set `partitionId` in the options passed to either `createBatch()` or `sendBatch()` methods on `EventHubProducerClient`. Use `createBatch()` if you want to safely batch messages so that they fit under the max size limit. Else use sendBatch() directly by passing array of messages.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/eventhubproducerclient?view=azure-node-latest#createbatch-createbatchoptions- 
 and
 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/eventhubproducerclient?view=azure-node-latest#sendbatch-eventdata----sendbatchoptions-